# How to extract information using awk on .gz files without storing the uncompressed data on disk

Tags: awk, gzip

I need to use this command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a{print}' inputfile1.txt inputfile2.gen.gz >output.txt
```

Awk doesn't read the .gz file.

I have tried

```
zcat inputfile2.gz | awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a{print}' inputfile1.txt inputfile2.gen.gz >output.txt
```

It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give Awk a dash argument to say to read its standard input.

```
zcat inputfile2.gz |
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next}
    $1 in a' inputfile1.txt - >output.txt
```

(Notice also I took out the `{print}` since that is already the implied default action in Awk.)

Comment: arg, too fast ...

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked beautifully! A few questions: a) if I want my output to be a gz file, I just say > ouput.gz?  b) what did the '-' do at the end? c) how does awk know that the zcat inputfile2.gz is the 2nd file from which the information is to be extracted?

Comment: No, Awk just reads and writes text, and only the files you tell it to.  You give it `-` to say "read standard input, not a file on disk". Pipe to `gzip` to compress the output.  `zcat | awk stuff ... | gzip >output.gz` and read up on pipes to understand how these pieces fit together.