# Using grep and looking for unique occurrences with awk comand

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

How can I use grep and look for unique occurrences with awk so I can have the number of occurrences for that value in the file but have also the name of the file?

I have tried this:

```
zgrep '2020-04-20|12345|' FILENAME_* |awk -F '|' '{print $2 "|" $3 "|" $4}' | sort | uniq -c
```

It gives the unique occurrences of the columns 2,3 and 4 of the file, but I want to know the name of the file where the occurrences exist. How can I do that?

Comment: `|awk -F'|' '{split($1,t,/:/); print t[1],$2 FS $3 FS $4}'` if there is more than one file _or_ `-H` is specified per binarysta, unless any filename(s) contains a colon then it's more complicated

Comment: If an occurrence of `X` is found in two or more files, how do expect/propose that the final counts are presented. Once for each file, or the sum of the occurrences of `X` together with a list of the files that it was found in?

Answer (score 1):

For **uncompressed** and **compressed** files, try:

```
for f in FILENAME_*; do
    zcat -f "$f" | awk '/2020-04-20\|12345\|/ {rec=$2 "|" $3 "|" $4; a[rec]+=1}  
         END {for (rec in a) print FILENAME " : " rec " : " a[rec]}'
done  > output.txt
```

A brief explanation:

- first loop over all your possible filenames with globbing (`*`).
- Use `zcat -f <filename>` to decompress your input file (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140002), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498589/72707) ...) on the fly if needed (`-f` option).
- `zcat -f <filename> | awk ...` uses the decompressed output of file `$f` as input for `awk`.
- for each pattern `2020-04-20|12345|` you find, increment the associative counter array `a` each time you encounter the value `$2 | $3 | $4` in a record parsed by `awk`.
- when you are finished parsing a file (`END` block) and for each component `rec` of the associative array `a`, concatenate-print the filename 'FILENAME', `rec` value `$2 | $3 | $4` and number of occurrences of that value `a[rec]`.
- `awk` makes some handy internal variables' such as the currently processed filename 'FILENAME' available to you.
- The single redirection of the `for` loop's successive outputs to `output.txt` is completely optional. If you suppress that, you will
  just output to `stdout`.

===================================

*This answer was **EDITED** and improved, based on @AdminBee's, @roaima's @dave_thompson's and @kusalananda's many useful comments.*

Comment: Glob _doesn't_ work in quotes; that's exactly backward. Doesn't work for compressed files, as required. Doesn't give counts as desired.

Comment: Also beware that the `|` symbol in the regexp-based match condition `/2020-04-20|12345|/` will be interpreted as "OR", so you need to escape this or it will match also lines containing only `2020-04-20`, only `12345`, and many others due to the "empty" last alternative ...

Comment: Would this actually print the correct filenames and not just the filename resulting from the process substitution?